# AutoMapper creates empty objects instead of null

Tags: automapper

I recently upgraded AutoMapper from 6.0.2 to 6.1.1 and got a problem:

```
public class Entity1
{
    public Entity2 MyEntity2 { get; set; } // Entity2 is a class
    public Guid MyEntity2Id { get;set; }
    // Other parameters...
}

public class ViewModel1
{
    Guid Entity1Id { get; set; }
    // Other parameters...
}
```

The mapping:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Entity1, ViewModel1>.ReverseMap();
```

With version 6.0.2:

```
var myEntity1 = Mapper.Map<Entity1>(viewModel1);
```

after this mapping myEntity1.MyEntity2 is null.

After upgrading to v 6.1.1 I run exactly the same mapping but myEntity1.MyEntity2 is an empty Entity2 object and this creates a lot of problems.

Can anyone tell me how to change the mapping so myEntity1.MyEntity2 is null after the mapping?

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same problem today.  After a bit of research, I found the following page: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2693

The culprit was `ReverseMap()`.  Once you remove that call, Automapper starts working correctly (null source creates null destination object, instead of an empty object).  So in your case you would have to replace this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Entity1, ViewModel1>.ReverseMap();
```

with this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Entity1, ViewModel1>();
cfg.CreateMap<ViewModel1, Entity1>();
```